# I would like to prepend an ascending set of numbers to a row of text cells in Excel

Tags: excel, cells, prepend

So I have a row of cells that have questions

```
Blah | blah2 | blah3 ||| blah73
```

I'd like to make it so it looks like this

```
Q1: Blah | Q2: Blah2 |||| Q73: blah73
```

How do I do this in excel without having to do it manually?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so then please mark one as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an empty row:

```
="Q" & Column(A:A) & " " & A1
```

Where A1 is the first cell in the row with `Blah`.  You only need to change the A1 to the first cell and drag across

Comment: Thanks, you're smart

Comment: I concur, you're smart :)

Comment: the teacher cannot be a teacher if he is not also a student :)